# Extension method to create list of objects of a class using property values of other class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-3.5

I have created a Extension method for IQueryable class to convert list of a Generic source class to list of other generic destination class,(.net3.5)
I'm using reflection to get properties from source object value and assign it to destinvation object.
The source code of the class is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace System.Linq
{
    public static class QueryableExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<TDest> ToDTO<TDest>(this IQueryable<TSource> source)//getting error on this line
        {
            return DTOTranslator<TDest>.ConvertToDTO<TDest>(source);
        }
    }

    public class DTOTranslator<TSource>
    {
        public static IQueryable<TDest> ConvertToDTO<TDest>(IQueryable<TSource> source)
        {
            List<TDest> destinationList = new List<TDest>();
            List<TSource> sourceList = source.ToList<TSource>();

            var sourceType = typeof(TSource);
            var destType = typeof(TDest);
            foreach (TSource sourceElement in sourceList)
            {
                TDest destElement = Activator.CreateInstance<TDest>();
                //Get all properties from the object 
                PropertyInfo[] sourceProperties = typeof(TSource).GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo sourceProperty in sourceProperties)
                {
                    //and assign value to each propery according to property name.
                    PropertyInfo destProperty = destType.GetProperty(sourceProperty.Name);
                    destProperty.SetValue(destElement, sourceProperty.GetValue(sourceElement, null), null);
                    destinationList.Add(destElement);
                }
            }

            return destinationList.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

however at compile time I am getting the error on line 12:

```
The type or namespace name 'TSource' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to all for reply.

Now I've updated my class as follows:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TDest> ToDTO<TSource, TDest>(this IQueryable<TSource> source)
    {
        List<TDest> destinationList = new List<TDest>();
        List<TSource> sourceList = source.ToList<TSource>();

        var sourceType = typeof(TSource);
        var destType = typeof(TDest);
        foreach (TSource sourceElement in sourceList)
        {
            TDest destElement = Activator.CreateInstance<TDest>();
            //Get all properties from the object 
            PropertyInfo[] sourceProperties = typeof(TSource).GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo sourceProperty in sourceProperties)
            {
                //and assign value to each propery according to property name.
                PropertyInfo destProperty = destType.GetProperty(sourceProperty.Name);
                destProperty.SetValue(destElement, sourceProperty.GetValue(sourceElement, null), null);
                destinationList.Add(destElement);
            }
        }

        return destinationList.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

This works fine,

now the only thing I wonder is that-

Is it possible to skip the `<TSource>` paramerter,

how to read it from the IQueryable's element type and define its object?
I mean currently I call the method as

```
IQueryable<CATEGORY_DTO> dtos = (from p in new MyEntities().CATEGORY select p).ToDTO<CATEGORY, CATEGORY_DTO>();
```

I want to call it as

```
IQueryable<CATEGORY_DTO> dtos = (from p in new MyEntities().CATEGORY select p).ToDTO<CATEGORY_DTO>();
```

Thanks, NJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TDest> ToDTO<TDest, TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source)
    {
        return DTOTranslator<TSource>.ConvertToDTO<TDest>(source);
    }
}
```

The addition being that the `ToDTO` method also references the `TSource` generic type (since otherwise how can you reference is as a parameter - this led to the original error), and this generic type is given in the constructor for `DTOTranslator` (since it is an error to use `TDest` in the constructor, as the definition of the generic type needed in the constructor itself is `TSource`, which is a different type from `TDest`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare both type parameters:

```
public static IQueryable<TDest> ToDTO<TSource, TDest>(this IQueryable<TSource> source)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but is it possible to get the type of objects in IQueryable list coz I want to pass only the destination type parameter?

Comment: This doesn't compile, since the `DTOTranslator` constructor needs a different generic type (`TSource`) then that used in the signature of the `ConvertToDTO` method.

Comment: @NitinJS: You could put the TDest parameter on the class instead of the method, then the compiler can use type inference to get the type of TSource without having to specify it.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your function signature as bellow and a little change in your convertor, I assumed you can't pass source type else you can add generic parameter as input to your functions.

```
public static IQueryable<TDest> ToDTO<TDest>(this IQueryable source)
{
   return DTOTranslator<TDest>.ConvertToDTO<TDest>(source);
}

public static IQueryable<TDest> ConvertToDTO<TDest>(IQueryable source)
{
    Type sourceType = null;
    ....
    foreach(var item in source)
    {
       // find source type is it not found till now
       if (sourceType == null)
         sourceType = item.GetType();
       ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yaakov's answer is correct to your question as asked, and i have upvoted accordingly.  i think there's a better answer, though.

as an alternative to writing your own reflection code for mapping as you are here, consider using automapper.

http://automapper.org/

this is a problem that has already been solved and is well-tested and used by a lot of folks and it has a lot of capabilities and flexibilities and handles a lot of edge cases you may not be considering.  i suggest you check it out.

also wanted to add that it's a little strange that you are using the system.linq namespace.  system should be reserved for stuff in the framework class library and i would suggest you use a namespace of your own.  it's not critical, but i would think it would be confusing to you and to any other users of your code to use something like that.